# Domain of $\log({\sin({x-3})}) + \sqrt{16 - x^2 }$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\log({\sin({x-3})}) + \sqrt{16 -  x^2 }$$

I did some manipulations and found that the Domain of $\sqrt{16 -  x^2 }$ is $[-4 ,4]$ and Domain of $\log({\sin({x-3})})$ is ${\pi\over2}(2n + 1) + 3 \ge x \ge n\pi +3$

But now i don't know how to get the given answer of $3 - 2\pi \ge x \ge 3 - \pi \text{ and } (3 ,4)$

It would be great if somebody can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You need the domain of $x$ for which each function is defined.

Comment: ...not the domain of the functions of x.

Comment: @amWhy I think we can use domain of f(x) in short for domain of definition of f(x).

Comment: As long as we're all on the same page, user377111! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $\sin(x-3)$, where x is any real number is [-1, 1].  The domain of log p is p > 0, since log is not defined for real numbers less than or equal to 0.  So the range on $\log(\sin(x-3))$ is (-infinity, log(1))

EDIT: based on question edit

domain has to be where 0 $\lt\sin(x-3)\le$ 1 and where $\sqrt{(16-x^2)}\ge$ 0

Further:

$\sin{(x-3)}\gt$ 0, when x $\in$ (3-4$\pi$,3-3$\pi$) $\cup$ (3-2$\pi$,3-$\pi$) $\cup$ (3,$\pi$+3) $\cup$ (2$\pi$+3,3$\pi$+3). This is a subset of (3+2n$\pi$,3+(2n+1)$\pi$), where n is an integer.

now you have to consider also, x $\in$ [-4,4]

you can decide that 3-3$\pi\lt$ -4, this means that you can ignore the values of x below this.  However, 3-2$\pi\gt$ -4. On the other end, $\pi$ + 3 is greater than 4, so x has to be in the open interval (3,$\pi$+3), but no greater than 4.

Therefore the domain I get is 3-2$\pi$ < x $\lt$ 3-$\pi$ and (3, 4]

Comment: This does not answer my question. I already did all this.

Comment: What is this thing?

Comment: I did not see your edit, until I posted the answer initially.

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness My humblest apologizes for that. I am getting hard headaches in real analysis.

Comment: Composition of functions:  domain of $\sqrt{(16-x^2)}$ is [-4,4], domain of $\sin{(x+3)}$ is all real, but you have to consider that the domain of $\log{x}$ is x > 0.  So You have to find x, where $\sin{(x+3)}\gt$ 0

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness I did this and got the domain of $\log({\sin({x+3})})$ as ${\pi\over2}(2n + 1) + 3 \ge x \ge n\pi +3$

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness i edited the question.

Comment: Yes, that would change things.  change my $\sin{(x+3)}$ to $\sin{(x-3)}$  should work out.  Then $\sin{(x-3)}\gt$ 0 where ever  2n$\pi$+3$\lt$ x $\le$  (2n+1)$\pi$+3,  where n is an integer.  Then you have to take the intersection of this and [-4,4].

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness That is where i am facing trouble.I know intersection operation but  I don't know how to take intersection with these two sets. Can you please show me ? Sorry for troubling you. I will accept your answer if you show me the correct way.

Comment: Ok.  Give me a minute and I will put it in as an edit in the answer.

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness Please do so, that would a great help.

Comment: Check your given answer, because I think the $\pi\over2$ should maybe be just $\pi$

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness Last thing, How do you get $x \in (3, 4]$ i did not get that, can you explain on it ? nevertheless, Nice answer.

Comment: Back with you shortly

Comment: Yes, basically 4 $\in$ [-4,4] and in (3,3+$\pi$) so the "end point" is contained in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the argument of $\ln$ defined, we need for $$0\lt \sin(x-3) \leq 1  \iff 0 \lt x- 3 \lt \pi\iff 3\lt x \lt \pi + 3$$

or, for $k \in \mathbb Z$ $$3+2k\pi \lt x\lt (2k+1)\pi + 3$$ or $$(2k+1)\pi +3\gt x \gt 3+2k\pi\tag 1$$

Now, we can't forget that the domain for $x$ when $f(x) = \sqrt{16-x^2}$ is $$-4\leq x \leq 4\tag 2$$

So the overall intersection of these domains remains to be determined.

We need to take $k = -1$, in order for x to remain within $[-4, 4]$.  This gives us $$-4 \lt 3 - 2\pi\lt x \lt 3-\pi \lt 4$$ but also, we have $$x \in (3, 4]$$

Comment: Take $k = -1$  This gives us $$-4 \lt 3 - 2\pi\lt x \lt 3-\pi \lt 4$, but also, we have $x \in (3, 4]$

Comment: Ok got it. Can you explain how did we got $x \in (3, 4]$, i did not get that part ? Thanks.

Comment: Because if $k=0$, then we have have $x\lt \pi + 3,$ but $\pi + 3 \gt 4$.  Have you tested how, say $x= 3.1,$ and \or $ x = 4$? Note that $x = 3 \in [-4, 4]$ and that $x = 3$ gives us $\sin (3-3) = \sin 0 =0$. So we can't include $x = 3$, but we can include any $x\in (3, 4]$  Is $\sin (4-3) = \sin 1>0?$ same with all $x\in (3, 4]$ since it meets both criteria

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks for the answer. Anyway some latex error in your comment.

Comment: Hope this helped!